# How can I return the array object from Array's prototype function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, prototype, chaining

I have a programming exercise to create two prototypes of Array, they are both functions. I have put my code below. One will be called on the other as shown in the last line. I am trying to get the second function to modify the value that would have been returned by simply calling the first function. That is for the code below, I want the output to be [4,6,4000], I instead get the length of the array after push, i.e. 3 in this case.

```
Array.prototype.toTwenty = function() 
{
    return [4,6];
};
Array.prototype.search = function (lb)
{

    if(lb >2)
    {
        //This doesn't work
        return this.push(4000);
    }
};

var man = [];
console.log(man.toTwenty().search(6));

//console.log returns 3, I need it to return [4,6,4000]
```

my searches led me to `arguments.callee.caller` but didn't try that as that's being deprecated and I can't use it.

Please could someone help me? I've tried to read prototype inheritance, chaining and cascading but can't seem to extract an answer. Thanks for any help

Comment: *"I have a programming exercise to create two prototypes of Array"* Your assignment is to add functions to the `Array.prototype`, not to create two prototypes of Array (which would be impossible).

Comment: 1. There's no reason that `toTwenty` should be on `Array.prototype`, since it doesn't use the array, it just returns a new one. It should be on `Array`. 2. If you're going to add to `Array.prototype`, it's best to use `Object.defineProperty` and make the addition non-enumerable. Why is covered indirectly in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting MDN on [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push),

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array.**

So, `this.push(4000)` actually pushes the value, but as you are returning the result of `push`, you are getting the current length of the array which is `3`.

---

Instead, you should return the array object itself, like this

```
Array.prototype.toTwenty = function () {
    return [4, 6];
};

Array.prototype.search = function (lb) {
    if (lb > 2) {
        this.push(4000);            // Don't return here
    }
    return this;                    // Return the array object itself.
};

console.log([].toTwenty().search(6));
// [ 4, 6, 4000 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it,

```
<script>
    Array.prototype.toTwenty = function() {
        return [4, 6];
    };
    Array.prototype.search = function(lb) {

        if (lb > 2) {

            return this.push(4000);
        }
    };

    var man = [];
    man = man.toTwenty();
    man.search(8);
    console.log(man);
</script>
```

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/tovfz2er/)

Comment: My code is being evaluated via test driven development (I just got explained that term three days ago!). I have to create code that would be called in the toTwenty().search() format, unfortunately I can't change that.